# Getting conflicts while using multiple forms in one view page in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

i am trying to submit a hidden form that contain the per_page and current_page details as a param values for paginating the search results , but the same view page contain the search form also . but while submitting the hidden form by using .submit() method in AJAX for paginating the search results i am getting conflicts between these 2 forms . could any one please tell what we need to care about while using 2 forms in one view page in Rails .

Comment: could you please come up with an example of your view? and the response from the ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can have n number of forms, but they should not be nested.

your html should be liek foloowing

```
<form id="form_1">
</form>
<form id="form_2">
</form>

|
|
|

<form id="form_n">
</form>
```

and to submit `form_1` using jquery use [`.submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) method of jquery as following

```
$('#form_1').submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

remove nesting of forms  and if nessary that it will see under another use iframe for inner one